# Não é possível converter implicitamente void em string em classes abstratas

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Meu código de classes abstratas possui dois erros:

- Não é possível converter implicitamente "void" em "string" (Linha 5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23, 24)

```
using static System.Console;

public abstract class DevilHunter
{
    public string Slogan() => Write("Devil May Cry!"); 
    public virtual string Profissao() => Write("Caçar demônio");
}

public class Dante : DevilHunter
{
    public string Estilos() => Write("Possuo 4 estilos de luta");
    public override string Profissao() => Write("Caço dêmonio em grande eSSStilo");
}

public class Nero : DevilHunter
{
    public string DevilBreaker() => Write("Uso Devil Breaker");
    public override string Profissao() => Write("Caço dêmonios ao som de música eletrônica");
}

public class Nico : Nero
{
    public string Dirigir() => Write("Dirige furgão");
    public override string Profissao() => Write("Armeira responsável por criar Devil Breakers para Nero");
}

public class Imprimir
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dante dante = new Dante();
        Nero nero = new Nero();
        Nico nico = new Nico();

        Write(dante.Profissao());
        Write(nero.Profissao());
        Write(nico.Profissao());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: o método main deve ser um `static X Main()` na `static class Program` onde X é o tipo de retorno, normalmente `void`, mas pode ser `int` também

Comment: @RovannLinhalis isso não deu certo

Comment: só uma observação: você não possui nenhuma classe abstrata, e a dúvida não é sóbre isso... sem saber como vc fez as alterações e onde está tentando compilar também fica difícil. Estando no visual studio, você deve ter a classe estática Program, com o método estático Main que é onde o programa vai iniciar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A estrutura está errada para o que está tentando fazer, isso se, o que estás a tentar a fazer é imprimir as funções das classes no Console.

Você atualmente tem a estrutura de classe:

```
class DevilHunter
{
    public string Slogan() => Write("Devil May Cry!"); 
    public virtual string Profissao() => Write("Caçar demônio");
}
```

A classe `DevilHunter` tem dois métodos onde devem retornar `String`, no entanto, o corpo de ambos métodos chamam o método `Console.Write`, e o mesmo não retorna nenhum valor, apenas escreve no Console aquele texto.

Se quiser que os métodos retornem os textos para usar em outro lugar (que é o ideal), convém usar propriedades de forma que retornem os textos adequadamente:

```
class DevilHunter
{
    public string Slogan => "Devil May Cry!"; 
    public virtual string Profissao => "Caçar demônio";
}
```

Ou se quiser que continuem sendo métodos que escrevam no Console, altere de `string` para `void`, já que não retorna nada:

```
public void Slogan() => Write("Devil May Cry!");
```

No entanto, a linha acima não irá retornar nada e não poderá ser chamada para atribuir valor à algo.

Outro erro dentro do seu `Main` é a chamada do `Write` para outro `Write`. Você precisa especificar um argumento válido para o método `Write`, e outro `Write` não retorna nada.

Usando propriedades, você poderá simplesmente passar a propriedade como String e funcionará corretamente. Também mudei o método para `WriteLine` para que exista uma quebra de linha entre cada profissão.

```
class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dante dante = new Dante();
        Nero nero = new Nero();
        Nico nico = new Nico();

        WriteLine(dante.Profissao); // public virtual string Profissao => "...";
        WriteLine(nero.Profissao);
        WriteLine(nico.Profissao);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

<sub>Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4DAZPS).</sub>

Já o método de inicialização depende de algumas coisas, como a versão do C# e qual compilador estás a usar. Se estiver a usar uma versão inferior ao C# 7.1, este método não funcionará. Deverá utilizar a assinatura `static void Main(string[])` e não outra, o que muda é que poderá ter ou não ter argumentos.

As assinaturas permitidas ao método do entrada, >= versão 7.1, são:

```
public static void Main() { }
public static int Main() { }
public static void Main(string[] args) { }
public static int Main(string[] args) { }
public static async Task Main() { }
public static async Task<int> Main() { }
public static async Task Main(string[] args) { }
public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args) { }
```

Na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/) você poderá entender melhor sobre. Na [referência da linguagem](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction) também diz sobre estas assinaturas.

Comment: Você foi mais rápido do que eu...

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu já havia respondi a 15 minutos atrás, no entanto, a resposta estava incorreta porque não estava no escopo da pergunta. Não o que havia entendido.

Comment: O padrão é procurar um método `Main` em qualquer lugar, não há padrão de nome de classe.

Comment: @LINQ tem razão, está descrito na referência da linguagem: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction

Comment: @CypherPotato Continua errado. O main pode ser sem parâmetros. https://i.imgur.com/uUouL0d.png. Na documentação que você cita diz isso: "The Main method can be declared with or without a string[] parameter that contains command-line arguments."

Comment: Tem razão, mas ficou confusa e dá um tom de que está incorreta. Porque parâmetro e visibilidade fazem parte da assinatura do método, então você dá a entender uma coisa diferente.

Comment: @LINQ se quiser, pode editar para colaborar com uma explicação mais simples.

Comment: Eu sei disso, mas preferi avisar. Não vou editar nenhuma publicação pra mudar o que ela diz.

Comment: Pra mim o problema ainda não foi resolvido

Comment: @CarlosA. o que não foi resolvido ainda? A resposta contém o conteúdo que você utilizará para resolver teu problema. Se não resolveu, sugiro editar sua pergunta com conteúdo mais claro.

Comment: @CypherPotato `linhas 5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23 e 24` estão com erro de `Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo void em string`.

Comment: @CarlosA. você aplicou o meu exemplo ou sequer leu a resposta? Confira o link do .NET Fiddle que coloquei e o código executará. Eu expliquei o porque este erro acontece no seu código e como podes resolvê-lo.

Comment: @CypherPotato me desculpe, agora deu certo o código está sendo executado, apenas fiz apaga tudo da minha IDE e copiar o seu código pra lá.

Comment: @CypherPotato por que com os métodos não davam certo?

Comment: @CarlosA. porque o retorno de suas declarações eram `string`, todavia, o corpo retornava diretamente uma função que não retorna nada (`=> Write()`). Os métodos `WriteLine` e `Write` apenas escrevem o que foi passado no Console, não retornam nada. Quando você especifica um tipo de retorno num método, obrigatoriamente ele deve retornar um objeto com o mesmo tipo do qual foi especificado.

Comment: Se mudasse de `string` para `void`, poderias chamar seus métodos e escreveriam no console os textos, no entanto, você não poderia chamar estes métodos como obtenção de valores posteriormente, porque eles são `void`s e não funções com retornos específicos.

Comment: Agora entendi, obrigado.